# What is definition of initially subamenable graph?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

In definition of [sofic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofic_group)  we define a **sofic group** is a group whose Cayley graph is an initially subamenable graph .

> What is definition of initially subamenable graph ?

Comment: There is a definition here https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/juschenko/files/soficgroups.pdf

Comment: @tomasz .Who is the author of this  lecture?

Comment: @tomasz . Author is Kate Juschenko ?

Comment: That's what it looks like, considering the file is hosted on her webpage. but I don't know. I found it via web search.